# Fetching instagram users who's followers count more than 1 million using API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I can fetch user data from `i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/${account}/info`, but I just wondering is it possible to fetch users who's follower count more than 1 million using API.

Because for now if I want to do that, the only way is to fetch many users, then filter them by their follower count. As there is an API rate limit so it is not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible through any of the official Instagram endpoints. You could try a 3rd party API like this: https://socialblade.com/business-api or possibly write a crawler for this page https://socialblade.com/instagram/top/100/followers to get the top 100 users.

These are the official documentation pages for the current Instagram APIs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Edit:

Here is a script that will get you a Pandas DataFrame with the top 38574 Instagram profiles and their respective followers from trackalytics. You can sort this easily from there.

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import locale, time
from tqdm import tqdm, trange

url = 'https://www.trackalytics.com/the-most-followed-instagram-profiles/page/1/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'}

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 
wp = r.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(wp, 'html.parser')
pages = soup.find(id='paging').next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element
pages = int(pages.split()[3])
row_collector = []
progress = tqdm(range(1,pages))
for page in progress:
  p_url = 'https://www.trackalytics.com/the-most-followed-instagram-profiles/page/' + str(page) + '/'
  tp = r.get(p_url, headers=headers).text
  tsoup = BeautifulSoup(tp, 'html.parser')
  rows = tsoup.findAll("tr")
  for row in range(1,25):
    profile = rows[row].find(style='vertical-align:middle;width:45px;height:45px;').next_element.contents[0]
    followers = rows[row].find(style='vertical-align:middle;width:45px;height:45px;').next_element.next_element.next_element.next_element.contents[0].split()[0]
    followers = locale.atoi(followers)
    temp = [profile,followers]
    row_collector.append(temp)
   # Enter rate limiting per page here
df = pd.DataFrame(row_collector)
df[['profile','followers']] = df[[0,1]]
del df[0]
del df[1]
display(df)
```

Preview dataframe with the top 25 profiles:

[image]

For me, this took ~20 minutes to run through the entire loop to pull 38,000 users.

Here is a Google Colab notebook if you would like to test the script:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/185o2fOdxRFHEsfvp7QOMILM6V2Rs9X22?usp=sharing

Comment: socialblade only available for top 5000, and it's a pay service. I have read through the official doc but no such api available.

Comment: @Eason I've updated my answer with a python script that will grab a much larger number of the top Instagram profiles.